# Digital pianos and/or midi keyboards with narrower keys

Tags: digital-piano, midi-controller-keyboard

Are there any digital pianos on market with good key action but with narrower keys?

Or at least MIDI-keyboards that have the proper length of the keys, but with slightly reduced width?

Comment: No, key size is standardized.  I wouldn't recommend that you work with a non-standard keyboard width anyway, because you would have a lot of difficulty playing any other keyboard.

Comment: @BobRhodes: As [this question](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20290/is-there-a-standard-width-for-piano-keys) shows, this is a de facto standard at best, but there seem to be no significant deviations.

Comment: @JBeurer Well, I've played a harpsichord with narrower keys than a piano.  It was like playing a different instrument, and it's always a good idea to learn more than one.  But I can easily reach an octave or a seventh or ninth without looking on the piano, because I know where they are. I don't recommend that the OP learn an instrument with narrower keys because he won't be able to play most of the keyboards out there.  So, my answer was intended as a practical one, and I'll stick with it as such.

Comment: @BobRodes why are all my comments gone?

Comment: @JBeurer I don't know. Either a technical problem, or some moderator deleted them, or some other explanation that doesn't occur to me.

Answer (score 1):

Some keyboards (mostly portable, keytars, or entry models for children) come with slim keys ([this](http://www.theverge.com/2014/1/23/5339576/korg-announces-rk-100s-keytar), for instance). However I am not sure if there is a good idea to start learning from them. [Here](http://www.marthabeth.com/electronic_keyboard_features.html) it says may not be good idea to play one size at home and another everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

purchase original F. Chopin Pleyel http://piano.pleyel.fr/piano-classique/piano-a-queue-p204-bleu-noir.html?lng=EN not sure that modern has narrow keys, the other unrealistic way is to ask people from Yamaha, Korg, Casio and Roland to make a digital copy of Chopin`s and Bach`s instruments. My Yamaha with dynamic light keys has a 3-4 mm narrower octave than the ones with hammer action pianos.