# What is the length of piano keys, in inches

Tags: piano, construction

I am working on a project for which I need the dimensions of piano keys. The width is addressed in

[Is there a standard width for piano keys?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/20290/70803),

but what about the length?

Comment: also depends on the piano, they're not all absolutely identical

Comment: I don't see why the fact that dimensions vary couldn't be incorporated into a reasonably concise answer..?

Comment: @topomorto  well, for one thing, because it's trivial to find out and very rare that any performer would care.

Comment: It does in fact seem that there's a question on this very site: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20290/is-there-a-standard-width-for-piano-keys. That one was pretty well-received...

Comment: @Tim you even answered that one - http://music.stackexchange.com/a/20301/18896

Comment: @topomorto - the older question has more depth than this, and if it's already answered, we don't need this question, do we?

Comment: @Tim sure, for the reason that it's a duplicate (IMO). *Apart* from that though, I was just wondering where the other concerns raised about this question come from w.r.t our on-topic rules.

Comment: It's not clear what the OP means by "dimensions of piano keys". The part of the key inside the piano is usually longer than the part that you play on, for example.

Comment: This question is on topic -- being about the design and construction of musical instruments -- and not a dupe since the OP is asking for *all* dimensions, not just width (if I'm interpreting him/her correctly).  The only mark against it (unclear what you're asking?)  is that he/she is a bit vague in not specifying which actual dimension he/she needs.

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure where you were going with the mention of finding an answer with Google in 25 seconds, but I think this might be edifying in terms of the vision on SE/SO for questions that could be answered with a Google search (TL/DR, we want to be the top hit on future Google searches, so we want the question and answer): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://music.stackexchange.com/q/20290/79479 since that question only discusses the width of keys, and not the length.

Comment: I found this thread and want to put in my 2 cents. It was interesting to read. At this time I have no piano, but I need to know the length of keys, in particular the proportion of black to white, as I'm knitting a piano keyboard scarf. I guess my point is that sometimes you're just looking for a simple answer.

Answer (score 10):

A Kawai studio model acoustic piano vintage 1980 or so that I have access to where I work has the following key dimensions (visible portion only, if you need the hidden part, which is much larger, let me know):

White key width = exactly 7/8 inch.  Visible length = 6 in., including a 1/16" "lip" on the top surface that sticks out beyond the end of the key proper.  Visible height when not depressed = 7/8 in.

Black key width at white key level = 15/32" tapering up to 7/16" at the top, which is 1/4 in. above white key level.  Length at white key level 3 15/16" tapering back to 3 5/8" at the top.

Horizontally across the width of the keyboard there is approximately 1/16" gap between keys.

When I get home tonight I'll measure my Panasonic 88-note electronic and see if it differs.  (For one thing I know it does not have the 'lip' on the white keys.)  If it is substantially different from the above I'll post a comment to this answer.

EDIT: Well, I was wrong about the lip on the white keys.  My electronic piano has them too!  I had never noticed that.  The white keys are exactly 1/8 in. shorter in length than on the acoustic, but otherwise identical.  The black keys are 1/16 in. wider and 3/16 in. taller, but otherwise identical.  So all in all the two pianos are so extremely similar as to be almost identical.  Certainly the 88 note keybed (where the notes are placed) is within 1/8" of being exactly the same length.  I have no idea what you needed all this for, but have fun with it!